# Ubuntu VMWARE Ruby Error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vmware

I am trying to run bundler. My ruby version is 2.3.0 but I keep getting this error.

Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0

Any help is appreciated.

Edit-
Ubuntu version is 14.04. 
ruby -v returns 2.3.0.
I am writing in notepad and compiling in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are more options to this problem as you did not specifi it to a larger extent. But the options are:

1. you could have more versions of ruby installed which leads to collisions
2. if you are using IDE, it could be linked to a wrong version of ruby
3. if you are not using IDE but terminal, the default ruby might be set to a wrong version

If its not one of these, than you should give us more information on your setup.

1. Version of Ubuntu
2. outputs of `rvm list` or `ruby -v` from terminal
3. What are you using to develop? IDE, vim, Sublime, ... etc.
4. How do you compile it
5. May be something more, but I cant think of anything now...

Comment: I have 2 versions of ruby installed. The first one is 2.1.2 which was the original version and since my gemfile specified 2.3.0, I installed 2.3.0.                               ruby -v returns 2.3.0                                                                                             Version of ubuntu is 14.04                                                                                             I have been using notepad and compiling it on terminal

Comment: Try running `gem install bundler` and then try `rbenv rehash`

Comment: rbenv rehash is returning error bash: rbenv: command not found